# Mounting Other partitions like windows does

Tags: mount, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and windows 8.1 dual booted in my dell laptop, whenever I boot my Ubuntu OS i have to manually click on the drive [say D drive on windows] to mount and open it. So all i have to do is keep those drive mounted permanently and I cannot even unmount or eject them like in windows.

Answer (score 2):

See [Automatically Mount Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)